# Я приму всё, что ни будет мне послано

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, это придаточное уступки или относительное придаточное?

Слово *всё* меня путает.

> Я приму всё, **что ни будет мне послано.**

Большое спасибо!

Comment: А что Вы понимаете под относительным придаточным предложенем?

Comment: мы называем такие предложения релативными и русские доценты учат нас как "относительное". но это именно то, как вы имеете в виду в вашем ответе

Comment: Мне вот кажется, что это предложение вообще звучит не по-русски, есть в нём какая-то чуждость. Я бы либо написал "_что бы ни было мне послано_", либо просто выкинул "_ни_" в исходном предложении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае это придаточное **изъяснительное** предложение, которое как раз необходимо для характеристики слова “всё“, вызвавшего у Вас сомнения. Для самопроверки необходимо задать вопрос “всё — это что?“, который, как я сам считаю, является наиболее уместным. Также можно задать вопрос “что именно?“. Определившись с вопросом, необходимо постараться ответить на него, что успешно получается.

Вот полезный сайт по теме https://lampa.io/p/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-0000000057b87d05da5ad4f5e0b6da56

Comment: спасибо за ответ! можно это предложение модифицировать чтобы получить придаточное уступки?

Comment: Да, вполне можно: “Я приму всё, несмотря на то что мне ни будет послано“.

Comment: sorry for being a pain in the ***! стараюсь построить пример с "как (бы) ни"/"какой (бы) ни"/"когда (бы) ни" etc. Плюс, придаточное должно быть в индикативе(!). Вы как носитель языка скажете так: "я приму всё, какие испытания судьба ни пошлет мне"?

Comment: Wow, do ya like using idioms?) Let me think about your question for 5 minutes.

Comment: В данном случае лучше построить предложение так: “Я приму всё — какие **бы** испытания судьба ни **послала** мне“. Однако здесь появляется логическое ударение.

Comment: jajajajajaja naahh, not that i like using them, i'm just trying to fit the example into the formulated rule =)

Comment: But it wasn't necessary to use that construction, was it?

Comment: thank you so much for your help! but that's the thing - мне обязательно надо чтобы придаточное имело индикативную форму =(

Comment: Тогда так: “Я приму всё — какие испытания ты ни пошлёшь, судьба“.

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much indeed! you're an angel!

Comment: если вы не против, возьму ваш пример но поменяю немного чтобы потом обвинение о плагиате не пришло мне =) у нас здесь очень строго

Comment: Конечно, делайте что хотите.

Comment: @Anonym Вполне возможно в этом предложении использовать глагол **ниспослать.** (См.: https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/ниспослать) Вот пример: _Я должна принять все, что будет мне ниспослано_ (Й. Пирс. Перст указующий).

Answer (score 3):

***Я приму всё, что ни будет мне послано.***

Хотя я сейчас практически не отвечаю на вопросы, но всё-таки иногда просматриваю темы. И вот структура этого предложения мне показалась интересной, так что пришлось даже уточнить  ее по учебнику **Кустовой «Синтаксис современного русского языка».** Там дан разбор подобных предложений, и я предлагаю воспользоваться этой информацией.

1) Уступительные придаточные имеют два подтипа:  **союзный и относительный.**

2) **Союзный подтип:** Уступительные союзы ХОТЯ, НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО. Пример:  Хотя  (несмотря на то что) шел дождь, мы отправились на прогулку.

3) **В относительном подтипе** используется **относительные местоимения и частица НИ:** КАК НИ, ЧТО НИ, КАКОЙ НИ и др. Пример: Какой бы ни была погода, мы отправлялись на прогулку.

4) Особое место во втором подтипе занимают предложения с **обобщенными местоимениями**  ВСЁ, ВСЕ, НИКТО и др., так как  они имеют **«настоящие» местоименные пары** (все/кто; всё/что).

Это сближает их с местоименно-определительными предложениями. Фактически это **средний подтип** между уступительными и относительными придаточными.

5) Сравнить:

(1) ***Я приму всё, что будет послано мне (судьбой).*** 
Это классический вариант местоименно-определительного (относительного) придаточного. Местоименная пара **всё/что.**

(2) ***Я приму всё, что ни будет мне послано.***

Местоименная пара **всё/что**, частица НИ.

Это **средний** вариант: разные школы относят такие предложения **как к относительным, так и уступительным придаточным.**

(3) Уступительное придаточное: ***Что ни пошлет мне судьба, я приму это с радостью.***

Здесь нет местоименной пары, как во втором примере, поэтому это  обычное уступительное придаточное.

6) **И вывод**:

Придаточное в заданном предложении можно отнести к **переходному** виду между уступительным и относительным.

**Признаки уступительного придаточного:** значение обобщения, усилительная **частица НИ.**

**Признаки относительного придаточного**: местоименная пара ***всё/что***, характерная для местоименной связи главного и придаточного предложений.

Comment: Куда же Вы исчезли, Sharon? Спасибо за "ликбез".

Comment: В смысле? Вот же я здесь, с вами.

Comment: Sharon: вы великолепны! спасибо за все время, которое потратили на меня! =)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Но я думаю, что приведенная информация многим будет полезна, в том числе и мне самой. Отвечая на интересные вопросы (а Ваш вопрос был интересным и нестандартным), учишься и сам.